# Linear regression in R using predict function

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction

I am very new to R and I made a linear model of price based on variables like size and location. I used data from 2005-2010 for the model (Model_Data) and I want to make predictions for 2011-2014 (Test_Data).

```
model=lm(Price~Size+Location, data=Model_Data)

Test_Data$Predicted_Price = predict(model, Test_Data)

df=data.frame(Test_Data$Predicted_Price)

write.csv(df, file="Predictions.csv")
```

When I run this and open the csv file, it returns all NA values for the 2011-2014 test data. There are some empty cells for some of the variables, but I thought those are just omitted when predictions are made. Is it something wrong with the code? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit **your question** according to guidelines stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's unclear which step is causing the issue. Run each line and inspect the inputs and the result if they match what you'd expect

Comment: You should add your dataset, or at least a subset of it.